# NetSuite user event script only ran once

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I deployed a user event script, which applies to Purchase Orders, with event "edit".
My script ran the first time I edited a purchase order, but thereafter it no longer ran. I recreated the entire script and deployment, but it is still not running.

I checked the list of scripts applied to purchase orders and my script is there. The script is deployed and released, with event type set to 'edit'.

Might this have something to do with usage limits? There was an error during the first execution of the script, where I did not supply a needed parameter, perhaps this caused an issue?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you select an audience when you released the script?  If there is no audience selected, the script won't execute.  Happened to me a couple of times.

Comment: I figured it out and this was the issue. It turns out I did not select die correct company subsidiaries, so the script did not run when it should. Thanks for the help!